# Insertion multiple records in the same objectContext

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, objectcontext, savechanges

I'm having some trouble when I try to insert data using the same objectContext.

My problem is, the **order** that the Entity read my code is not the order that I "Add" it.

Example:

**EntityAB** has **EntityA**'s PK as a FK. 
1-N relationship.

```
objContext.DbSet.Add(EntityA);
objContext.DbSet.Add(EntityAB);
objContext.SaveChanges();
```

Error Message when the code reach `SaveChanges()`:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EntityAB_EntityA". The conflict occurred in database "dbTest", table "dbo.EntityA", column 'IdEntityA'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

So, my entity framework is reading `objContext.DbSet.Add(EntityAB);` **before** `objContext.DbSet.Add(EntityA);`

---

If I change the code to:

```
objContext.DbSet.Add(EntityA);
objContext.SaveChanges();
objContext.DbSet.Add(EntityAB);
objContext.SaveChanges();
```

It works.

---

But I can't. It need to be done in **one** `SaveChanges()` because of the auditing.

My question is, 
 **CAN I OBLIGATE THE SAVECHANGES() READ THE CODE IN THE ORDER THAT I ADD IT?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your context set up?

I think the following might work..

in the context

```
public DbSet<EntityA> EntityAs { get; set; }
public DbSet<EntityAB EntityABs { get; set; }
```

then in your other code

```
objContext.EntityAs.Add(EntityA);
objContext.EntityAB.Add(EntityAB);
objContext.SaveChanges();
```

If that doesn't work I would explore

```
objContext.local
```

Comment: I Resolved it with something similar (It's look like a workaround, and I'm still trying to improve it.) I got the idea from @drch [in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9043123#9043123)